# ContextWrapper как добавить?

Tags: java, android

Создаю класс для чтения/записи вне Activity, код примерно следующий:

```
 FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

но "нужен ContextWrapper". Где и что надо прописать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [openFileOutput](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)) это метод класса `Context`. Т.е. его надо вызывать над экзепляром этого класса. Т.е. вам надо передать туда, где вы хотите его использовать ссылку на контекст.

Т.е. метод должен как-то так выглядеть:

```
public void method(Context context) {
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
        outputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```